# How to efficiently assign a value to a scipy sparse matrix like A[2,3]=1?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

It seems that assigning values to a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix element causes me a warning:

```
In [25]: A=csr_matrix((100000,100000),dtype=float)

In [26]: A[2,3]=1
/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:103: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
```

How can I do the simple "A[2,3]=1" assignment?

Comment: Use a better-suited sparse-format for random-access based mutation. Read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information) and pick a candidate. E.g. `dok_matrix`.

Comment: There's really no one right answer to this. Every assignment requires you to reallocate the underlying data. Best option is probably to batch assignments so you only have to do one big assignment instead of a bunch of little ones.